# Change country of content in new Apple TV app

Tags: appletv

I want to view Spanish content on the TV app, but I am just shown UK content.

My apple id is from the uk and all my devices are in english, but I live in Spain.

The new (Dec 2017) Apple TV App shows content from British apps, many of which don't work outside of the UK (BBC, itv etc).

I have changed the region of the Apple TV, but I still see the same content.

Is there any way to force the Apple TV App to show content for my local region?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/appletv/comments/71897s/tvos_11_cannot_change_storesregions/ that might help. I have similar issues with my AppleTV as I live in Ireland where Siri voice control is not available...

Comment: Make an Apple ID with your Spain address, and set the language to English.